# oauth_callback for Khan Academy API not woring

Tags: oauth, omniauth, khan-academy

We are working on wiring up our application with Khan Academy and I am not able to get a proper redirect back after authorizing the request token. I always get the default callback along with the body "OK" and NEVER get redirected back to the location specified on our oauth-callback.

I am getting a javascript error in the browser and I am wondering if this is the source of the problem. Here is an example of our authorize call (after successfully getting the request token):

```
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.kudoso.com%2Fauth%2Fkhan_academy%2Fcallback&member_id=2&oauth_token=t0000003404618819
```

The Javascript error I am getting is:

```
/genfiles/javascript/en/shared-package-8caf31.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: KA.staticUrl is not a function
```

I am getting this error in both Firefox and Chrome. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the callback is specified when obtaining the request token (see [section 6.1.1 of this document](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/)), not when performing authorization. Can you make sure you're doing that correctly and then confirm if you're still having trouble with the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many, many months, we finally figured out what is going on.  Khan Academy has a bug in their API where they do not support the oauth standard of including the oauth_callback in the header, but does allow you to submit it as a param.

We implemented a ruby fix here: https://github.com/DaKaZ/omniauth-khan-academy

Enjoy