# Javascript Khan Academy OAuth can't override default_callback

Tags: javascript, oauth, khan-academy

I've got this express app going;

```js
const oa = new OAuth(
  'https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/request_token',
  'https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/access_token',
  process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  '1.0',
  'http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback',
  'HMAC-SHA1',
  64
)

app.get('/oauth', (req, res) => {
  oa.getOAuthRequestToken(function requestTokenCallback(err, token, token_secret, results) {

    if (err) {
      console.log('requestTokenCallback', err)
      return
    }

    req.session.oauth = req.session.oauth || {}
    req.session.oauth.token = token
    req.session.oauth.token_secret = token_secret
    res.redirect(`https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize?oauth_token=${token}`)
    // I've tried res.redirect(`https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize?oauth_token=${token}&oauth_callback=${encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback')}`)
  })
})
```

However, clicking `accept` once the user is redirected does not redirect them to my callback, `'http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback'`.

This fellow seems to be having the same issue: [oauth_callback for Khan Academy API not woring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089044/oauth-callback-for-khan-academy-api-not-woring).
However, I followed the instructions of the answer and redirected with an `oauth_callback` param, with no avail.

I'm super new to oauth in general, but I don't believe that this is my fault. I just need some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `khan` npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/khan allows for the `oauth_callback` to be specified when calling `.requestToken()`. For example:

```
khan.requestToken('www.myapp.com/my_callback')
```

Passing in an `oauth_callback` parameter into the `.requestToken()` function ensures that the user being authenticated will be redirected to the specified site. This is a much lovelier solution than using the `node-oauth` due to the curried functionality, promises, and expressive semantics.